# Id clone is only cloning the first item that i click and not the rest

Tags: jquery

```
function publishHandler(){
var publish = new post();
publish.set("Title", storyTitle.value);
publish.set("User", Parse.User.current());
publish.set("Author", aruthor.value);
publish.set("Story", storyBox.value);
publish.save({
success:function(){
publishWindowHandler();
storyForm.reset();
 },
error:function (error){
alert("sorry your story was not published");
}
});
}




var  publishWindowHandler function(){

var query = new Parse.Query('Post');
console.log(currentUser); 
query.equalTo("User", currentUser);
query.include("User");
query.descending("createdAt")
console.log(user.get('username'));
// query.limit(4);
query.find({
success:function(results){
    document.getElementById("publishCenter").textContent = "";

    for(var i =0; i < results.length; i++){

    var userPost = results[i];



    var authorTitle = document.createElement("p");
    var newPost = document.createElement("P");
    var title = document.createElement("P");
    var userLabel = document.createElement("p");
    var postId = userPost.id;

    var postBtn = document.createElement("INPUT"); 
    postBtn.setAttribute("Type", "button");
    postBtn.setAttribute("value", "Publish");
    title.textContent = "Story: " + userPost.get("Title");
    authorTitle.textContent = "Author: " + userPost.get("Author");
    newPost.textContent = userPost.get("Story");
    userLabel.textContent = "Published by: " +                    userPost.get("User").get("username");

    var postWrapper = document.createElement("DIV");
    postWrapper.className = "postWrapper";
    postWrapper.id = postId;

    document.getElementById("publishCenter").appendChild(postWrapper);
    postWrapper.appendChild(title);
    postWrapper.appendChild(authorTitle);
    postWrapper.appendChild(newPost);
    postWrapper.appendChild(userLabel);
    postWrapper.appendChild(postBtn);

    postBtn.addEventListener("click", publicViewHandler);

    function publicViewHandler(){
    $("#" + postId).clone().appendTo(".storyBoard");

  };
```

i have thrown up a demo domain in case anyone wants to see what i am really talking about...
http://subdomain.jason-c.com/

test login is user kio and password is kio... when u login i have posted some lorem ipsum what im trying to accomplish is when i click push on my stories i want to coppie the selected story but its only cloning the same one nomatter what i click ... a clearfication to what i doing wrong would be awesome

Comment: ID's are unique, you can't have more than one element with the same ID, and you seem to be creating multiple elements with the same ID, which is invalid.

Comment: well im trying to clone the elements by their ids but when i click another element the it stil holding the id as the previous element that was first clicked...i know id are unique im not trying to clone the selected element that is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using `$("#" + postId)` in your click handler. You can't use variable `postId` in handler like this because there is different context in listener. With this little modification, your code works perfect.

```
function publicViewHandler(){
    $(this).parent('.postWrapper').clone().appendTo(".storyBoard");
};
```

Comment: Thank you I tried it and it works... this one was busting my head